# Trying to use divide and conquer to get all subarrays of an array

Tags: c++, vector, combinations, sub-array

The Basic idea is to use the [Maximum subarray solution](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/maximum-subarray-sum-using-divide-and-conquer-algorithm/) to generate all subarray of an array. But in order to implement that idea, I have been hit with a roadblock where I need to find all combinations of two vectors(left side of the mid and right side of the mid).

For example, if there are 5 elements in each of these vectors then if I choose 1 element from vector1 and then I have to choose one to five elements from vector2.

Similarly, if I choose 2 elements from vector1 then I have to choose one to five elements from vector2 etc.

The below is my try to implement the subarray for left and right sides.I need your help in implementing combinations of two vectors in c++.

```
for (int i = m; i >= l; i--) {
    sum = sum + arr[i];
    A[cnt].push_back(arr[i]);
    if (sum > left_sum)
        left_sum = sum;
}
int zsize=A[cnt].size();
int k1=cnt;
cnt++;
for (int i=0;i<zsize-1;i++)
{
   A[cnt]=A[k1];
   A[cnt].erase(A[cnt].begin()+i+1,A[cnt].begin()+zsize);
   cnt++;
}
```

Comment: If the first vector has N elements and the second has M, there are pow(2, M+N) combinations and factorial(M+N) + factorial(M+N-1) + factorial(M+N-2).... permutations.

Comment: Generally we go to great lengths in analysis of the problem to avoid having to actually work on all combinations/permutations (brute force).

Comment: Are you looking for contiguous subsets, which is what "subarray" usually means?

Comment: yes i am looking for contigous subsets to be generated less than O(n2) time

Comment: Well then you certainly cannot generate all of them.

Comment: is it possible to generate atleast the duplicate subarrays for example 12121 gives subarrays 121,121 can i only generate this duplicate subarrays in less than O(n2)

Comment: Do you know in advance the length of the subarray you are looking for?  Are you looking for the longest repeated sequence?  For example, the input `12121` has repeated subsequences of `1` (3 times), `2` (2 times), `12` (2 times), `21` (2 times), `121` (2 times).  If you need all of those, I'm afraid you are going to have O(N^2) complexity.

Comment: @BenVoigt i found this answer useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17638627/find-the-number-of-repeated-subarray-in-an-array but not know how to program it