# Subarrays in O(N) complexity

Tags: c++

I am stuck on finding a solution for finding all the contiguous subarrays of a given array in minimum time complexity O(n). For example: [1,2,3,4] Subarrays are: [1][2][3][4][1,2][2,3][3,4][1,2,3][2,3,4][1,2,3,4] I have done it with time complexity O(n^3) but question wants in O(N).

Comment: You can always show us what you've tried and explain you're reasoning. We can try and guide you from there.

Answer (score 3):

There are [image: (n*(n-1))/2] subarray as you described. Therefore, There is a lower bound of [image: O(n^2)] to your problem.

Comment: Yeah, most likely the real problem is "find sub-array with maximum sum" and OP missed the DP decomposition they could do.

Comment: @Jeffrey: Seems like a rehash of https://stackoverflow.com/q/67939667/103167 -- same requirement of "all subarrays" in "better than O(n^2)" which is of course not possible.  Then it became "all repeated subarrays".